# Getting TypeError: 'str' object is not callable while using print

Tags: python

```
def validation(Side,sideNumber):
    while 1:
        if Side<=0:
            print("Do not enter invalid inputs")
            Side=eval(input("Enter the "+str(sideNumber)+" Side : " ))
        else:
            return Side

S1=eval(input("Enter the First Side: "))
S1=validation(S1,"First")
S2=eval(input("Enter the Second Side: "))
S2=validation(S2,"Second")
S3=eval(input("Enter the Third Side: "))
S3=validation(S3,"Third")
if S1+S2>S3 and S2+S3>S1 and S1+S3>S2:
  print("The Triangle Formation is Possible")
else :
  print("The Triangle Formation is not Possible")
```

After running this program in Google Collab I am getting this error:

```
15 S3=validation(S3,"Third")
     16 if S1+S2>S3 and S2+S3>S1 and S1+S3>S2:
---> 17   print("The Triangle Formation is Possible")
     18 else :
     19   print("The Triangle Formation is not Possible")

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Earlier it was running Fine But now it keeps showing this.

Comment: Probably you defined ```print``` as a string

Comment: Code runs fine when I try it in python 3.8 - Maybe it's a 'Google Collab' thing?

Comment: Yes @Martin I also checked it on pycharm its working fine there , I think its a google collab issue, Btw thanks

Answer (score 0):

do not use return return statement in the while loop of the validation()

Comment: I am getting typeerror in print statement ,what does the return statement has to do with it anyway??